# Unable to use phangorn::phyDat

Tags: r, phylogeny

I am following an example from ‘Analysis of Phylogenetics Second Edition and Evolution with R’ from Emmanuel Paradis.

He is doing:

[image]

I am doing pretty much the same:

```
x=c('garras','garras','garras', 'tejido','tejido','tejido')
y <- phyDat(matrix(x), "USER", levels = unique(x))
```

but I get:

> Error in phyDat.default(data, levels = levels, return.index =
> return.index, : data object must contain taxa names

Screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? how come the example from the book works...

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, x needs to have (species) names.
This can be either a named vector:

```
x <- c('garras','garras','garras', 'tejido','tejido','tejido')
names(x) <- paste0("t", 1:6)
y <- phyDat(x, "USER", levels = unique(x))
```

Or a matrix with row names:

```
x <- matrix(x, dimnames = list(paste0("t", 1:6), NULL))
y <- phyDat(matrix(x), "USER", levels = unique(x))
```